# What is the point of replace function in Memcache?

Tags: php, memcached

What is the point of replace function in PHP memcache if you can just use set? Even if there is a variable, set automatically replaces it, right?

Can you give me an example where it's better to use replace instead of set?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, the [manual page](http://php.net/memcached.replace) says: “Memcached::replace() is similar to Memcached::set(), but the operation fails if the key does not exist on the server.”

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to PHP.net:

> [Memcached::replace() is similar to Memcached::set(), but the operation fails if the key does not exist on the server.](http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.replace.php)

Comment: Can you explain @evening's 2nd question about when is it better to use `replace` instead of `set`?

Comment: I can't give an example I'm afraid, I've never needed to use replace().

Answer (score 5):

Following on from ZoFreX's answer if you look at the comments here:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcache.set.php

You will see the following:

> Using set more than once for the same key seems to have unexpected results - it does not behave as a "replace," but instead seems to "set" more than one value for the same key.  "get" may return any of the values.
>
> This was tested on a multiple-server setup - behaviour may be different if you only have one server.

So really and truly `replace()` will look for an existing key first, and then replace it (if it exists), whereas `set()` will just add the key. I imagine it's always best to use `replace()` first considering it returns `FALSE` if the key is not found, in which case you'd use `add()` rather than `set()` since you know for sure the key doesn't exist. This ensures that you won't have any unintended mishaps. So you're code could be something like:

```
$replace = Memcached::replace($key, $var);
if ( ! $replace)
{
    $set = Memcached::add($key, $var);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally, replace should be used if the key is likely to be used frequently. Set/add/etc creates a brand new entry, and can lead to fragmentation and a lot of cleanup. Replace reuses the memory already allocated (if possible), and can be more stable and efficient. If it fails, using add/set will still work.

Answer (score 0):

nope that's entirely wrong.

If you want to check and set a value you must use GETS + CAS.

Comment: Can you explain how to use this to achieve a replace and why this is the correct solution?

Comment: What are you referring to when you say "that's entirely wrong"?